# Light and Dark Mode Not Working on MKDocs. the icon is missing, how to show it?

Tags: color-scheme, darkmode, mkdocs, lightmode, mkdocs-material

Yesterday I'm successfully add `light` and `dark mode scheme` on MkDocs-material
When I tried to add `auto match with system preferences` when I click to auto, the icon is missing. So I delete the code for auto and everything is working fine.

Today, I'm trying to add `auto` code again, but just like before when I click it, the icon is MISSING.

I try to delete the `auto scheme` and run `mkdocs serve`

BUT, NOTHING CHANGES

THE ICON STILL MISSING, what should I do to show up the toggle again? I've rewrite the code and restart my pc

Answer (score 0):

Open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in incognito mode and it should work